# How can I make a method stream agnostic?

Tags: rust, rust-tokio

I have the following method:

```
async fn transfer_all(stream: &mut TcpStream) -> Result<Vec<Vec<u8>>, Box<dyn std::error::Error>> {
  let mut packets: Vec<Vec<u8>> = Vec::new();
  let mut header = true;
  let mut length: usize = 0;

  let mut packet: Vec<u8> = Vec::new();
  loop {
    stream.readable().await?;

    if header {
      length = 5;
      packet.clear();
      packet.shrink_to_fit();
      packet.reserve(length);
    }

    let mut buf: Vec<u8> = vec![0u8; length];
    match stream.try_read(&mut buf) {
      Ok(0) => {
        break;
      }
      Ok(n) => {
        if header {
          length = u32::from_be_bytes(pop(&buf[1..])) as usize - 4;
          header = false;
          packet.append(&mut buf);
          packet.reserve(length);
          continue;
        }
        packet.append(&mut buf);
        packets.push(packet.clone());
        header = true;
      }
      Err(ref e) if e.kind() == io::ErrorKind::WouldBlock => {
        break;
      }
      Err(e) => {
        return Err(e.into());
      }
    }
  }

  Ok(packets)
}
```

It works with TcpStream but I need to also make it work with UnixStream. Since this is a fairly convoluted state machine I'd rather not have two implementations. It was suggested to me to use `async fn transfer_all<S: AsyncRead + Unpin>(stream: &mut S) -> Result<Vec<Vec<u8>>, Box<dyn std::error::Error>>` and replace `match stream.try_read(&mut buf) {` with `match stream.read(&mut buf).await {` but this blocks when there's no more data to read. How can I make this method work with TcpStream and UnixStream?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since both `UnixStream` and `TcpStream` have a `try_read` method, you can make your own trait for them:

```rust
trait TryRead {
    // overlapping the name makes it hard to work with
    fn do_try_read(&self, buf: &mut [u8]) -> Result<usize>;
}

impl TryRead for TcpStream {
    fn do_try_read(&self, buf: &mut [u8]) -> Result<usize> {
        self.try_read(buf)
    }
}

impl TryRead for UnixStream {
    fn do_try_read(&self, buf: &mut [u8]) -> Result<usize> {
        self.try_read(buf)
    }
}
```

Then, you can take a `S: AsyncRead + TryRead + Unpin` then replace `try_read` with `do_try_read`.

Or, with a macro for reduced repetition:

```rust
trait TryRead {
    // overlapping the name makes it hard to work with
    fn do_try_read(&self, buf: &mut [u8]) -> Result<usize>;
}

macro_rules! make_try_read {
    ($typ: ty) => {
        impl TryRead for $typ {
            fn do_try_read(&self, buf: &mut [u8]) -> Result<usize> {
                self.try_read(buf)
            }
        }
    }
}

make_try_read!(TcpStream);
make_try_read!(UnixStream);
```

Comment: Where is try_read implemented for UnixStream? Can't find it at all.

Comment: [It's only in Tokio 1.0.0 and above.](https://docs.rs/tokio/1.0.1/tokio/net/struct.UnixStream.html#method.try_read)

Comment: In that case why do I need a whole extra trait? Can't I have a generic function that just takes TcpStream or UnixStream?

Comment: @ruipacheco Sadly, no.